# Cairo-Dock is no longer a dock?

Tags: cairo-dock

Cairo-Dock doesn't seem to work correctly as a dock since a few updates ago.

None of Cairo's docks are being displayed on my machine, now.

Some of their applets that I had separated from their dock are now stacked on each other at center screen.  The Cairo-Dock app itself now appears in the left launch bar, and displays a menu when right-clicked.

Is there a fix for this ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Did this issue came up suddenly after restarting the computer? Or is it a new installation?

Comment: Have you looked into the Cairo-Dock to see if they have support or if there are any know issues.

Comment: Archisman: Ubuntu version is 22.04.  The issue started after an update about 3 months back.

Comment: David: I haven't tried contacting them directly, yet.

Comment: David:  Their web site has a forum, but the most recent posts were in 2016.  Makes me wonder if it's still under development.  Kinda sad... I used it extensively.